# Could hydrogen peroxide (H2O2) be used as a 'disinfectant' on hospital patients that are in contact with SARS-CoV-2?

Tags: virology, coronavirus, infectious-diseases

Hydrogen peroxide kills harmful pathogens and various forms of bacteria by destroying their cell walls, through a process called oxidation. However, since SARS-CoV-2 is [acellular](https://www.scripps.edu/covid-19/science-simplified/parts-of-a-coronavirus/); not composed of a defined cellular structure, would hydrogen peroxide still function as an antiseptic in this case?

I am aware that there are other forms of cleaning and disinfection products which has being proven to kill SARS-CoV-2, however, I am curious to understand the practical applications of hydrogen peroxide.

Comment: i did a google search(you did not)you can take a look at part 7 here to find an answer to your question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide.it is expected that you do a minimum of research before asking a question,a more focused question will often get you better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "[List N](https://cfpub.epa.gov/wizards/disinfectants/)" from the USA CDC and check out the chemicals used for disinfection that have been tested and found effective against SARS-CoV-2.

[Hydrogen peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide) (H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>) can be used as an antiseptic at low concentrations, but would generally not be used in a clinical setting for control of a virus. It would generally be used as a [treatment for cleaning of minor wounds](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/what-is-hydrogen-peroxide-good-for/), but is no longer considered to be a suitable cleaning agent for this purpose because of irritation of the skin that happens as a result of application. It can not be used internally.

High concentrations (over about 5%) can produce severe burns on skin and other organs by inhalation or ingestion. Proper PPE used correctly is essential when using these products.

You can, however, as the list N suggests, use it very well as a cleaning agent. It is very bleaching, so it is not a good idea to use it on clothes or materials that are darkly coloured without testing them first.

Comment: High-concentration $H_2O_2$ can also produce sometimes severe burns on unprotected skin, as anyone who has performed immunohistochemistry has probably learned...

Comment: @MattDMo - yes, I think I should have stated that clearly, rather than by implication - will edit in.